# Process.Start("name.exe") - how is 'name.exe' found?

Tags: c#, windows, process, environment-variables

With the `C#` code:

```
Process.Start("name.exe");
```

I was wondering where does `Process` look to locate `name.exe`?

Comment: It would start looking in the same dir as your main exe i guess.

Comment: `Process.Start("notepad.exe");` also works though, and that is not in my application's folder

Comment: Thats why I said `start`. I expect it works like $PATH from unix, anything you can open in your command line will also be considered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will search the current working directory, the path of the executing exe, or any directory in `%path%`.

Comment: Do you have evidence? I question "the path of the executing exe". What if UseShellExecute is true? In that case AppPaths come into play. A question like these needs a comprehensive answer with multiple documentation links.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My answer is based on experience, whenever I have done this it has worked for me.

Comment: You should base answers on facts and evidence.

Answer (score 3):

From [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx);

> Starting a process by specifying its file name is similar to typing
>   the information in the Run dialog box of the Windows Start menu.

It should search the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

As quoted by another answer:

> Starting a process by specifying its file name is similar to typing
>   the information in the Run dialog box of the Windows Start menu.

But I happen to know that the Run dialog box does at least one thing beyond searching the `%path%` and/or working directory and/or the executable directory:

Registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` provides mapping from a file name typed in the Run dialog box to a full pathname of the application. It's a common practice for installers to add subkeys there, to enable starting the program with "Run" even if it's somewhere in `...\Program Files\...`.

Answer (score 0):

It will look into your Application Exe folder.
Normally its in `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release`

Answer (score 0):

DLLs are located according to this [search pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

1. The directory where the executable module for the current process is
   located.
2. The current directory.
3. The Windows system directory.
4. The Windows directory.
5. The directories listed in the PATH
   environment variable.

Most likely EXEs follow same pattern.